# Drag and drop JS components

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am making a website (to design mobile pages) with simple drag and drop, and I would like to know if there are libraries or framework supports the drag and drop components, and makes my life much easier.

Comment: Do a search for 'jquery draggable droppable' - it'll be the first link you come to. (Edit: ah, I didn't spot that you want this for mobile - not sure about that!).

Comment: There also are non-jquery drag and drop libraries. Also check http://microjs.com/# for smaller standalone scripts

Comment: Ah, I was right first time around - but this time add 'mobile' to your [search query](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jquery+draggable+mobile). Plenty to go on there!

Comment: @halfer I think he doesn't want to run it on a mobile page. Instead, he wants to CREATE mobile pages with it.

Comment: @Ahatius - thanks. Me and my hasty editing! Edit: although the tags "mobile" and "jquery-mobile" are rather misleading. OP, please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

- [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) seems to have drag and drop plugins.
- [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) seems to have native support.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Zenklys, jQuery would be one option! It's so powerful! I'm only just learning a little.

Checkout this great tut on ***jQuery Selectors*** that demonstrates how html elements can be selected and operated on - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eQI90xYez0. The **UI library** has draggable, droppable, resizable, selectable & sortable interactions with tons of widgets  like dialogs, slider, datepickers etc. I'm sure you'll find at east some of them useful in your application.

**draggable** - see http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

**droppable** - see http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

As well as great documentation, they have really good, on-the-page examples/source code and most UI assets can be invoked with a single line call.

Anyways, hope it's useful! Best of luck,

Gez